# I get a negative number for the denominator

Tags: java, junit, fractions, greatest-common-divisor

I wrote a program that adds two fractions and if the denominator is 0 it should throw `IllegalArgumentException`. When I test it, I get a failure, when I try to add `0/2 + -1/2` I should get `-1/2` but instead I get `1/-2`, how can I solve this problem?

The language is german, `bruch` means `fraction`, `neuNenner` means `new denominator`, `neuZaehler` means `new numerator` and `ggt` is the `gcd`.

I deleted

```
assertEquals("Zaehler = -1 Nenner = 2",
                rechnen.Rechnen.bruchAddition(0, 2, -1, 2));
```

but then I got this error `java.lang.AssertionError`

this is my code:

```
    public class Rechnen {

    public static String bruchAddition(int z1, int n1, int z2, int n2) {

        int neuZaehler = (z1 * n2) + (z2 * n1);
        int neuNenner = n1 * n2;

        int ggt = ggt(neuZaehler, neuNenner);
        neuZaehler = neuZaehler / ggt;
        neuNenner = neuNenner / ggt;

        if (n1 == 0 || n2 == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        return ("Zaehler = " + neuZaehler + " Nenner = " + neuNenner);

    }

    static public int ggt(int x, int y) {
        if (y == 0) {
            return x;
        }
        return ggt(y, x % y);
    }
}
```

this is the JUnit Test Case:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;
public class RechnenTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertEquals("Zaehler = 1 Nenner = 1",
                rechnen.Rechnen.bruchAddition(1, 3, 2, 3));
        assertEquals("Zaehler = 1 Nenner = 1",
                rechnen.Rechnen.bruchAddition(5, 8, 3, 8));
        assertEquals("Zaehler = 1 Nenner = 1",
                rechnen.Rechnen.bruchAddition(10, 16, 3, 8));
        assertEquals("Zaehler = 1 Nenner = 3",
                rechnen.Rechnen.bruchAddition(-1, 3, 2, 3));
        assertEquals("Zaehler = -1 Nenner = 2",
                rechnen.Rechnen.bruchAddition(0, 2, -1, 2));
        assertEquals("Zaehler = -2 Nenner = 3",
                rechnen.Rechnen.bruchAddition(-1, 3, 1, -3));
        try {
            rechnen.Rechnen.bruchAddition(1, 1, 1, 0);
            fail();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            assertTrue(true);
        }
        try {
            rechnen.Rechnen.bruchAddition(Integer.MAX_VALUE, 1, 1, 1);
            fail();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            assertTrue(true);
        }
        assertEquals("Zaehler = 1 Nenner = " + Integer.MAX_VALUE,
                rechnen.Rechnen.bruchAddition(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 1,
                        Integer.MAX_VALUE));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure Euclid's algorithm for GCD (`ggt`) works well with negative numbers.  I think you may want the result of `ggt` to be positive always.  It's probably best to make sure `ggt` is only called with positive integers (or 0 for the numerator):

```
int ggt = ggt(Math.abs(neuZaehler), Math.abs(neuNenner));
```

In Java, if `x` is negative and `y` is positive, `x % y` will be negative, which I think is why you're getting the negative results you're getting.

**EDIT:** To answer the second question (why you're getting an `AssertionError`): The problem is that you're overflowing.  You're adding two fractions whose denominator is Integer.MAX_VALUE, and your algorithm multiplies the two values to get `neuNenner`.  Of course, this will produce a result greater than Integer.MAX_VALUE, and so `neuNenner` will have the incorrect value, messing everything up.  Possible solutions: (1) use `long` values inside `bruchAddition` and `ggt`; (2) use `BigInteger`, which will let you handle integers of any size; (3) don't test with Integer.MAX_VALUE (try Short.MAX_VALUE instead); (4) change `bruchAddition` to handle special cases where `n1 == n2` (you can then just add the numerators), or `n1` is divisible by `n2` or vice versa (you can then multiply a numerator by `n1/n2` or `n2/n1` which would avoid handling numbers larger than `n1` or `n2`).

**EDIT 2:** To further clarify solution (1): it won't work just to change the declarations from `int` to `long` like this:

```
public static String bruchAddition(int z1, int n1, int z2, int n2) {

    long neuZaehler = (z1 * n2) + (z2 * n1);
    long neuNenner = n1 * n2;
```

because the multiplications are still done using `int`s, and will still overflow, *before* the value is casted to a `long`.  However, I've tested this and it works:

```
public static String bruchAddition(int z1, int n1, int z2, int n2) {

    long neuZaehler = ((long)z1 * (long)n2) + ((long)z2 * (long)n1);
    long neuNenner = (long)n1 * (long)n2;
```

to make sure all the computations are done using the larger integer size.  Also change the result type and parameters types of the `ggt` method to `long`, and change the `ggt` variable to `long`, but you don't need to do any other casting.

Comment: It worked!
I changed the code to `int ggt = ggt(Math.abs(neuZaehler), neuNenner);` and it worked. But I still get the `java.lang.AssertionError` error in the JUnit Test Case `RechnenTest`.
How can it be solved?

Comment: Sorry to bother you, I'm just a begginer in programming, I tried using the 4 solutions but they didn't work, maybe I did something wrong. Did you try one of the solutions?

Comment: @Maged Yes, I've tried #1, but I realized that some additional explanation might be useful.  See my second edit.

Answer (score 1):

Check the signs on both the numerator and denominator after the operation. If they're both negative or the numerator is positive and the denominator is negative, flip both signs.

Comment: I used the debugger and noticed the signs, as you said, they flip!
So I used `int ggt = ggt(Math.abs(neuZaehler), neuNenner);` and it solved the problem. But I get this `java.lang.AssertionError` in the `RechnenTest` JUnit Test Case, I can't figure out how to solve it!